# Tensorflow Executor failed to create kernel on GPU

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

I am trying to train a network using tensorflow on GPU. But this warning is thrown out during the training process.

I checked free memory size of the gpu. It seems ok.

> E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:623] Executor failed to > create kernel. Invalid argument: Default AvgPoolingOp only supports 
>   NHWC on device type CPU
>           [[{{node vgg_src/pool1}} = AvgPool[T=DT_FLOAT, 
>   data_format="NCHW", ksize=[1, 1, 2, 2], padding="SAME", strides=[1, 
>   1, 2, 2], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]
>   (vgg_src/conv1_2/Relu)]]

Although I can train and run the network properly, I still want to know what causes this problem. And how could I fix this problem?

--

#### Update

Add the code of my model which is a modified vgg-16 network.

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pdb

vgg_mean = [0.485, 0.456, 0.406]
vgg_std = [0.229, 0.224, 0.225]
data = None
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
# dir_path = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(dir_path, os.pardir))
weights_path = os.path.join(dir_path, 'models', 'vgg16_onnx.npy')

class Model():
    def __init__(self, vgg16_npy_path=None):
        global data

        if vgg16_npy_path is None:
            path = weights_path

            print(path)

            if os.path.exists(path):
                vgg16_npy_path = path

            else:
                print("VGG16 weights were not found in the project directory!")
                exit(0)

        if data is None:
            data = np.load(vgg16_npy_path, encoding='latin1')
            self.data_dict = data.item()
            print("VGG16 weights loaded")

        else:
            self.data_dict = data.item()

    def build(self, bgr_input):
        '''notice that opencv load image with bgr order, but the pretrained model is designed for rgb'''
        blue, green, red = tf.split(axis=3, num_or_size_splits=3, value=bgr_input)

        rgb = tf.concat(axis=3, values=[
            (red - vgg_mean[0])/vgg_std[0],
            (green - vgg_mean[1])/vgg_std[1],
            (blue - vgg_mean[2])/vgg_std[2],
        ])


        self.conv1_1 = self.conv_layer(rgb, "conv1_1")
        self.conv1_2 = self.conv_layer(self.conv1_1, "conv1_2")
        self.pool1 = self.avg_pool(self.conv1_2, 'pool1')

        self.conv2_1 = self.conv_layer(self.pool1, "conv2_1")
        self.conv2_2 = self.conv_layer(self.conv2_1, "conv2_2")
        self.pool2 = self.avg_pool(self.conv2_2, 'pool2')

        self.conv3_1 = self.conv_layer(self.pool2, "conv3_1")
        self.conv3_2 = self.conv_layer(self.conv3_1, "conv3_2")
        self.conv3_3 = self.conv_layer(self.conv3_2, "conv3_3")

        self.pool3 = self.avg_pool(self.conv3_3, 'pool3')

        self.conv4_1 = self.conv_layer(self.pool3, "conv4_1")
        self.conv4_2 = self.conv_layer(self.conv4_1, "conv4_2")
        self.conv4_3 = self.conv_layer(self.conv4_2, "conv4_3")

        self.pool4 = self.avg_pool(self.conv4_3, 'pool4')

        self.conv5_1 = self.conv_layer(self.pool4, "conv5_1")
        self.conv5_2 = self.conv_layer(self.conv5_1, "conv5_2")
        self.conv5_3 = self.conv_layer(self.conv5_2, "conv5_3")

        self.pool5 = self.avg_pool(self.conv5_3, 'pool5')
        self.fc6 = self.fc_layer(self.pool5, 'fc6')
        self.fc7 = self.fc_layer(self.fc6, 'fc7')
        self.fc8 = self.fc_layer(self.fc7, 'fc8')
        self.data_dict = None

    def avg_pool(self, bottom, name):
        return tf.nn.avg_pool(bottom,
            ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME', name=name)

    def max_pool(self, bottom, name):
        return tf.nn.max_pool(bottom,
            ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME', name=name)

    def conv_layer(self, bottom, name, stride = 1):
        with tf.variable_scope(name):
            filt = self.get_conv_filter(name)

            conv = tf.nn.conv2d(bottom, filt, [1, stride, stride, 1], padding='SAME')
            conv_biases = self.get_bias(name)
            bias = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, conv_biases)
            mean = self.get_mean(name)
            variance = self.get_variance(name)
            offset = self.get_beta(name)
            scale = self.get_gamma(name)
            norm = tf.nn.batch_normalization(bias, mean, variance, offset, scale, 1e-20 )
            relu = tf.nn.relu(norm)
            return relu

    def fc_layer(self, bottom, name):
        with tf.variable_scope(name):
            shape = bottom.get_shape().as_list()
            dim = 1
            for d in shape[1:]:
                dim *= d
            x = tf.reshape(bottom, [-1, dim])

            weights = self.get_fc_weight(name)
            biases = self.get_bias(name)

            # Fully connected layer. Note that the '+' operation automatically
            # broadcasts the biases.
            fc = tf.nn.bias_add(tf.matmul(x, weights), biases)

            return fc

    def get_mean(self, name):
        return tf.constant(self.data_dict[name][4], name = "mean")

    def get_variance(self, name):
        return tf.constant(self.data_dict[name][5], name = "variance")

    def get_gamma(self, name):
        return tf.constant(self.data_dict[name][2], name = "gamma")

    def get_beta(self, name):
        return tf.constant(self.data_dict[name][3], name = "beta")

    def get_conv_filter(self, name):
        return tf.constant(np.rollaxis(np.rollaxis(np.rollaxis(self.data_dict[name][0], 1), 2), 3), name="filter")

    def get_bias(self, name):
        return tf.constant(self.data_dict[name][1], name="biases")

    def get_fc_weight(self, name):
        return tf.constant(np.rollaxis(self.data_dict[name][0], 1), name="weights")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not GPU-memory size issue.

Read the thread.

https://github.com/tensorpack/tensorpack/issues/263

You may be need to change  the code according to the thread

TensorFlow only supports NHWC on cpu, 
Check out these two lines in this thread. May be you need to change the parameter

```
-        with argscope([Conv2D, AvgPooling, BatchNorm, GlobalAvgPooling], data_format='NCHW'), \
+        with argscope([Conv2D, AvgPooling, BatchNorm, GlobalAvgPooling], data_format='NHWC')
```

with argscope([Conv2D, AvgPooling, BatchNorm, GlobalAvgPooling], data_format='NHWC')

Comment: Thx Rabindra! What really bothers me here is that I think I do **not** use cpu to do the calculation. I just run the code by `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 python train.py` and there is no such thing  `with argscope([Conv2D, AvgPooling, BatchNorm,...` in my code.